# How to display a button inside a b-tabs in boostrap vue?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

this is the situation:

We have a series of tabs, which have card-like elements inside. The designer choose to push a "change display" feature which hides part of the content of the cards (image, description) to increase the displayed number per time.

The problem:

The designer choose to put this change display button, in the tabs section. Like (Tab - Tab - Button).
After a couple hours of research, I couldn't find a way to place a button inside the `<b-tabs>` component (which has X number of `<b-tab>`). I had to use float, position absolute and use coordinates to place the button, but obviously this is not a desirable solution.

Is there a better approach to this problem? Or it's possible to place the button inside the component itself?

Thanks.

Edit:

@Anatoly gave the answer !

Thanks.

Comment: Does it answer your question https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#add-tabs-without-content?

Comment: maybe you could provide a reproducible example ?

Comment: @Anatoly I think I could make it work with that, thanks. Gonna try and update after :) !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tabs without a content, described [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#add-tabs-without-content)